# Merge data from two cells in a row to one, repeat with all cells in column

Tags: vba, excel, merge

Essentially, I have some code that will create two columns of data.
I need to concatenate the cells that are next to each other horizontally (A1:B1 merged, A2:B2 merged, A3:B3 merged etc) but none of the code I've found seems to help.

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: Please check [How to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like,

```
dim rw as long
application.displayalerts = false
with worksheets("sheet1")
    for rw = 1 to .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
        .cells(rw, 1) = join(array(.cells(rw, 1).value2, .cells(rw, 2).value2), chr(32))
        .cells(rw, 1).resize(1, 2).merge
    next rw
end with
application.displayalerts = true
```

Comment: Isn't formula easier? Something like `=a1&b1` in column c and drag down? Edit: oh, you took merged literally.

Comment: I was under the impression that the cells had to be physically merged. Of course, given the general ambiguity of the question I could be totally off-base. tbh, sometimes I just want to see how much code I can write before I write a syntax error.